# AccountKit UI language

Tags: android, localization, account-kit

I have an app with only support one language, Bahasa Indonesia. So how can I change the Facebook's accountKit language into our supported language?

I've try the guide which told me to put this config in the `build.gradle` and the accountKit UI is still in english.

```
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "id"
}
```

Is there any way to change the language without changing the device language?

Comment: Yeah. The whole app is written in Indonesian. So it feels out of place when AccountKit's UI is in English.

Comment: have you found the solution yet ?

Comment: Not yet. We decide to let it as the way it is for now.

Comment: I've got the solution. I added a answer below as some may find this helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the solution! Just change the locale of the activity which contains the account kit and the UI language will be changed automatically. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/languages) is a list of supported languages for Account Kit.

I've added following code to achieve Bengali language in onCreate() of the activity from which the Account Kit intent is called:

```
 String languageToLoad = "bn";
 Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
 Configuration config = new Configuration();
 config.locale = locale;
 getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

And the result is this :

[image]

Comment: And how exactly do you did that? Please elaborate. I'm kinda stuck here :(

Comment: Ow. I thought `config.locale = locale;` and `resources.updateConfiguration()` is deprecated. Is it still save to use it?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'm using this for target sdk 25, no problem whatsoever ...:) have you applied it yet ?

Answer (score 0):

The Indonesian two letter code is usually "in" not "id".

Comment: "in" for Indonesia only exist in Java. Not in any other language. The standard itself using "id" for Indonesia. Because "in" will refer to India.