# How to change language in facebook accountkit UI in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to localization in facebook accountkit. when I change app language to French but accountkit can't change the language to French. It is still in English. And the OTP message also the same problem. so can anyone tell me how I can change the language in accountkit?

For example, below link is Android Example. But i need the ios type..
[AccountKit UI language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303854/accountkit-ui-language)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The system does not support changing your app's localisation on the fly. What I mean by this is, if system puts any UI components like alert or document picker on your behalf then the language which is used by system is device's default language and not the language you set in your app.

So, changing your device's default language should change language in facebook accountKit UI.

Comment: Thank you for response. i already try that process.. but it does not change.

Comment: How to change the localization file.

Comment: I got the answer. i'm changing the plish localization native development region. it's working.

Comment: Great. Please add your answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all document regarding

> **[Supported Languages for Localization in Account Kit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/languages)**

You can also custumize it

> [Customizing the Account Kit UI for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/ios/customizing)